# how to have communication between uclinux installed on cortex-m3 and fpga

Tags: fpga, cortex-m, uclinux

hi i have a fpga chip having cortex-m3 as hard-ip with it,i installed uclinux on cortex-m3 .
i wrote a c code which turns on 8 leds according to the number i give (it runs good on uclinux ) but now i want to give input number from c code on uclinux and transfer it to fpga ,then fpga will process on it and will glow the Leds,but i havn't find a way to do that(communication between uclinux and fpga).

for e.g. i can communicate with pendrive using uclinux cause i have the driver for it or i can write for any other device but how to show fpga circuit as device to uclinux,
one way i thought was as uclinux can access any address of cortex-m3 using pointers similarly i can do it for fpga ,but i don't understand how a digital circuit on fpga can have addresses.

Comment: _"then fpga will process on it"_ - the fact that you're asking this question at all suggests you've not yet implemented the FPGA logic to do that. It would be rather hard to get through the whole design and synthesis process without having considered where to route the input _from_, and at that point it should be readily apparent what the CPU core's view of the other side of that interface is.

Comment: Do you know how to set or change the bits of the cortex device you have in uclinux? Do you have a schematic of your connection between the MCU and the FPGA? Do you even know what an FPGA is?

Comment: its a simple code I have implemented a serial in parallel out register in FPGA fabric using verilog,the data will come from uclinux and then register will send it to leds,  fpga fabric and cortex-M3 are  connected using  AMBA (AHBlite ) bus protocol ,but when uclinux takes over i don't have any access to amba bus

Comment: If you can write to a hardware register that controls LEDs, you can probably also write to several to make a mailbox scheme. Your comment that you cannot access the bus when uClinux takes over suggests a lack of familiarity with how the operating system manages the hardware at low level. In many uClinux cases it really doesn't do much of that at all - no MMU may mean no memory protection and nothing to keep even a user mode program from writing directly to memory mapped I/O.  But a more sophisticated approach is to do it in a kernel driver.  Try to find an example that does something similar.

Comment: Does ucLinux provide /dev/mem? That'd be the quick and easy 'get it going' hack for manually poking whatever MMIO registers at the AHB/FPGA boundary that your logic is (or ought to be) on the other side of. From there it's a not-too-big step to [writing a simple char driver](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) to do it properly.